# RubyOnRails - search in the database by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

I have in my db a attribute where i save the record creation date.
The saved date has this format:

2013/06/18 19:03:24

I need to search only for date and i am not interested the time

I have try in this mode but it's doesn't work:

```
Report.find_all_by_created_at("2013-06-18").each do |r|  %> 
  [...]
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that `created_at` is a Rails generated column you can't really and just for created at date. Reason for that is in database `created_at` is saved as timestamp (or Datetime) so records created on 18th of June may have values from `2013-06-18 00:00:00` to `2013-06-18 23:59:59`.

So, if you'd like to select all objects created on specific day you should do something like

```
Report.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?, Date.new(2013,6,18).beginning_of_day, Date.new(2013,6,18).end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a range to where:

```
date = Date.new(2013,6,18)
Report.where(created_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)
```

This creates a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports` WHERE `reports`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2013-06-18  00:00:00' AND '2013-06-18 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but you could do:

```
Report.where("created_at >= ? and created_at < ?","2013-06-18","2013,06-19").each do |r|
  [...]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are collecting it as a `DateTime` and you would probably be able to use the `to_date()` method to change it to a `Date` object which would be searchable.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date

Answer (score 0):

you can use like matcher in sql query

```
Report.where("created_at LIKE '2013-06-18%'")
```

or look at the `Squeel` gem it can call SQL functions in ruby like syntax then you could use something thati will generate query with

```
WHERE cast(created_at as date) = '2013-06-18'
```